# Como hacer un Join entre 2 tablas de diferentes bases de datos en el mismo servidor, con Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Como hacer un Join entre 2 tablas de diferentes bases de datos en el mismo servidor, con Laravel

Hola, estoy algo perplejo, no encuentro información concreta al respecto, como si los creadores de Laravel no lo hubieran resuelto.

Tengo en un único y mismo servidor, dos bases de datos. En cada base hay una tabla y necesito hacer un JOIN entre estas tablas. Si bien se declarar una de las conexiones (base1), no entiendo como declarar la segunda conexión en la query. Aclaro que no estoy trabajando con eloquent.

Este es el codigo básico de un join clasico con una conexión, donde no se como sumar la segunda: DB::connection('base2')

Agradecere ayuda.

```
$resultado = DB::connection('base1')->table('mitabla1')
->join('mitabla2', 'mitabla1.id', '=', 'mitabla2.id')
->select('mitabla1.id','mitabla1.nombre','mitabla1.email','mitabla2.provincia','mitabla2.localidad')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo como lo siguiente:

```
$resultado = DB::connection('base1')->table('mitabla1')
->join('bd2.mitabla2 AS mitabla2', 'mitabla1.id', '=', 'mitabla2.id')
->select('mitabla1.id','mitabla1.nombre','mitabla1.email','mitabla2.provincia','mitabla2.localidad')
->get();
```

Reemplazas los nombres de `bd2` por el nombre de tu segunda base de datos y `mitabla2` por la tabla que quieres unir.